# Use virtual topic in ActiveMQ with postfix

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

I have a virtualtopic **topic.vt.order** and my two consumerqueues **topic.vt.order.consumer.A** and **topic.vt.order.consumer.B**.
My problem is that the consumerqueues not receive the messages that I send to my topic **topic.vt.order**.

Here is my configuration (activemq.xml)

```
<destinationInterceptors>
  <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    <virtualDestinations>
      <virtualTopic name="topic.vt.>" postfix=".consumer.*" selectorAware="false"/>
    </virtualDestinations>
  </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works!
Here you can see my configuration:

```
    <destinationInterceptors>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
            <virtualTopic name="topic.vt.>" postfix=".consumer.*" prefix="" selectorAware="false"/>
        </virtualDestinations>
    </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

You have to set a value for attribute "prefix". If you set it to blank it works!